# API hit count per client across multiple servers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, performancecounter

Using Spring-boot-actuator API I need to count the number of API hits per clientID. How can I achieve this? Another challenge is my application is deployed on AWS and Azure. At any time I want to know the total API hit count across all environments.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it. You have use tools like [newrelic](https://newrelic.com/) to capture that.
It uses java agent to bound to each API call.

Another option is you can use logging system to push logs and then accumulate and show using splunk, kibana. there you can create dashboard based on logs to check API hit.

You can implement your own approach, as an API interceptor/ControllerAdvice to send request hit in a separate async thread.But then you have to implement real time aggregration of these hits.